# How to use Jekyll to sort posts by a custom YAML front matter variable?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to create a page in my Jekyll site that will display a custom variable and list the posts that contain that custom variable.

I have created a movie review blog using a template Thiago Rossener created: 
Thiago's Template: https://github.com/thiagorossener/jekflix-template
My Site: https://www.howdareyoureview.com/

in each post, I have defined custom variables in the YAML front matter that relate to the movie's details (i.e actor, director score, etc.)

for example:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Baby Driver"
image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/how-dare-you-review/image/upload/c_fill,h_399,w_760/v1529865791/baby-driver.png'
tags:
- action
score: 72
director: Edgar Wright
written-by: Edgar Wright
staring: 
- Ansel Elgort
- Lily James
- Eiza González
- Jon Hamm
- Jamie Foxx
---
```

I want to create pages exactly like the tags page that already exists in this template: 
https://www.howdareyoureview.com/tags/

except I would want to sort by director, starring, etc. instead of by tags.
the tags page is created using the following code in a tags.html file:

```
---
layout: minimal
title: "#Tags"
permalink: /tags/index.html
description: "Procure por sua #tag favorita."
---

<div class="tags">
{% assign tags_list = site.tags %}
  {% if tags_list.first[0] == null %}
    {% for tag in tags_list %}
        <a href="#{{ tag | slugify }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for tag in tags_list %}
        <a href="#{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% assign tags_list = nil %}
</div>

{% for tag in site.tags  %}
    <div class="tag-wrapper">
    <span class="tag-title" id="{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</span>
    <ul class="post-list">
        {% assign pages_list = tag[1] %}
        {% for post in pages_list reversed %}
            {% if post.title != null %}
            {% if group == null or group == post.group %}
            <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}<span class="entry-date"><time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ post.date | date: "%m/%d/%Y" }}</time></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% assign pages_list = nil %}
        {% assign group = nil %}
    </ul>
</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

To achieve this for the custom variables I created I tried replacing "tag/tags" with director and saving the file out into to root directory as "directors.html" but the page is blank.

```
---
layout: minimal
title: "#Directors"
permalink: /directors/index.html
description: "Procure por sua director favorita."
---
<div class="directors">
{% assign directors_list = site.director %}
  {% if directors_list.first[0] == null %}
    {% for director in directors_list %}
        <a href="#{{ tag | slugify }}">{{ director }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for director in directors_list %}
        <a href="#{{ director[0] | slugify }}">{{ director[0] }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% assign directors_list = nil %}
</div>

{% for director in site.director  %}
    <div class="director-wrapper">
    <span class="director-title" id="{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ director[0] }}</span>
    <ul class="post-list">
        {% assign pages_list = director[1] %}
        {% for post in pages_list reversed %}
            {% if post.title != null %}
            {% if group == null or group == post.group %}
            <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}<span class="entry-date"><time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ post.date | date: "%m/%d/%Y" }}</time></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% assign pages_list = nil %}
        {% assign group = nil %}
    </ul>
</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Since the code and the concept is exactly the same as the way tags are populated - I cannot understand why this doesn't work - I'm hoping someone can assist!

Here is my entire directory for reference: 
https://github.com/howdareyoureview/howdareyoureview.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags page uses `site.tags`, which is an array of `site.posts` grouped by tag, created by Jekyll at generation time.

You're trying to replicate by targeting `site.directors` but this expected array doesn't exist. But, you can use the group_by filter to achieve your goal.

```
<div class="directors">
  {% assign directors = site.posts | group_by: 'director' | sort: "name" %}
  {% for director in directors %}
    {% if director.name == "" %}
      {% assign name = "Anonymous" %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign name = director.name %}
    {% endif %}
    <a href="#{{ name | slugify }}">{{ name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% for director in directors %}
<div class="director-wrapper">
  {% if director.name == "" %}
    {% assign name = "Anonymous" %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign name = director.name %}
  {% endif %}
  <span class="director-title" id="{{ name | slugify }}">{{ name | debug }}</span>
    <ul class="post-list">
      {% assign pages_list = director.items %}
      {% for post in pages_list reversed %}
        <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}<span class="entry-date"><time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ post.date | date: "%m/%d/%Y" }}</time></a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Tip : You can use the inspect filter to debug your vars. `{{ myvar | inspect }}`

Comment: lHow can I use this if my front matter variable is space separated array? For example, I have variable `words: hello world sun` in some posts and I want to get posts by those words (all posts with `hello`, `world` or `sun`).

Comment: @FilipŠ, ask a real SO question. More chances to get help.